# Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel ID per widget on same page

Tags: widgets, twitter-bootstrap, id

I have integrated bootstrap Carousel into a WordPress widget. Carousel requires a unique ID per each for the controls to work. So if I am using 2 widgets that means 2 carousels on the same page the carousel controls won't work and some issues might happen.

I googled how to get widget id considering that each widget should have a unique id in the database which I can retrieve and assign it to the carousel ID which creates a unique id and let the controllers work. I couldn't find any suitable solution, anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0):

For Googlers looking for a solution after hours of research `spl_object_id` is your solution.

Read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php

Example:

```
<?php
$id = spl_object_id($object);
?>
<div id="carousel<?php echo $id;?> class="carousel">
```